# In Ashcroft and Mermin SSP, is 18.28 wrong?

Tags: solid-state-physics, textbook-erratum

I have been going over LEED in Ashcroft and Mermin independently. I believe equation $(18.28)$ has a factor of $2 \pi$ which should not be included. It would be in the dot product of $a$ and $b$, then cancel on both sides.

${\boldsymbol q} \cdot {\boldsymbol d} = 2 \pi n$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$

${\boldsymbol q} = q_1 {\boldsymbol b}_1+ q_2 {\boldsymbol b}_2+q_3 {\boldsymbol b}_3$
and
${\boldsymbol d} =n_1 {\boldsymbol a}_1+n_2 {\boldsymbol a}_2$

where  $q_1 = 2 \pi\, n$,  $q_2 = 2 \pi \,m$, and $q_3 = \mathrm{arbitrary}$

${\boldsymbol q}$ and ${\boldsymbol d}$ are vectors, defined from ${\boldsymbol a}_i$ direct lattice vectors, ${\boldsymbol b}_i$ reciprocal lattice vectors.

Just wanted to check with someone since this book is supposed to be infallible.

Comment: I seem to recall quite a few errors in the text, so I'd say that someone who said it was infallible probably hasn't read it too deeply. That said, it might be useful to include the relevant equations (this site has [MathJax enabled](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for LaTeX use) that you disagree with and want to apply.

Comment: @KyleKanos I have added the equations in question.

Comment: i just TeX edited your post for you. Keep in mind we require TeX syntax on this forum. Welcome to physics.stackexchange!

Comment: OK, so you've posted some $q\cdot d$ equations.  Where's the dot product of $a$ and $b$ as in your first sentence?